# Foreach: Proper way to add line breaks (paragraph) for specified number of rows

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I have a bunch of random sentences in a mysql database and I have no issue pulling them out and displaying them using the code below, but, I'm stumped on this next process.

How can add nl or encapsulate in

tags for every X number of rows? The selected rows are already limited to 14 (arbitrary) and my goal is to take those 14 rows and add a line break every 3 or 4 (also arbitrary) so they're more fluid looking paragraphs.

```
    <?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dbConnect.php';
$q = $dbc->query("SELECT DISTINCT sentence FROM sentences ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 14");

    while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    foreach($r as $value) {
$value = str_replace('$keyword', '<b>replaced keyword</b>', $value);
echo $value." ";  
    }

    endwhile;

?>
```

The code above works great for doing this:

Sample Output:

```
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
```

However, I'd like it to do something more like this without creating an inefficient 3 blocks of the same code with limits for 3, 2, and 4 or similar.

```
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.

This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.

This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
This is a complete sentence that I'm outputting to the page.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php 
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dbConnect.php';
$i=0; $j=0;
$seq=array(3, 2, 4);
$q = $dbc->query("SELECT DISTINCT sentence FROM sentences ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 14");

    while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    foreach($r as $value) {
         $value = str_replace('$keyword', '<b>replaced keyword</b>', $value);
         echo $value."<br>";
         if($i==$seq[$j])
         {
             echo "<br>";
             $j++;
             $i=0;
             if($j==count($seq)) $j=0;
          } else {
             $i++;
          }
    }
    endwhile;
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach to your question:

```
$numberOfSentencesPerParagraph = 4; // specify
$totalNumberOfSentences = 14; // or use a count function to calculate the number of returned MySQL records // or make this equal to a new variable you will introduce in your SQL query (after `LIMIT`)
while($r = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):
    $theCounter = 1;
    foreach($r as $value) {
        $value = str_replace('$keyword', '<b>replaced keyword</b>', $value);
        echo $value." ";  
        $theCounter++;
        if(($theCounter % $numberOfSentencesPerParagraph) == 0){
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
endwhile;
```

It simply runs a 'counter' and when its value is a multiple of the variable `$numberOfSentencesPerParagraph`, it `echo`es out a line break.